# Where can I see contact form submissions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have built my own website without the use of wordpress. It is only using HTML, CSS, JS (with Jquery and bootstrap).

I have built a contact form asking for Name, email, phone number, message. 
I'd like to know where to find the submission data? 
If there is a simple code I can just attach, if I necessarily have to build a database? What's the simplest way if I just want to have access to the submitted info?

Here is the contact form:

```
            <form method="post">
                <input type="text" value="Name" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Name';}" required="">
                <input type="email" value="Email" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Email';}" required="">
                <input type="text" value="Telephone" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Telephone';}" required="">
                <textarea type="text"  onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Message...';}" required="">Message...</textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
            </form>
```

Thanks

Comment: Use PHP and `var_dump($_REQUEST);`, `have to build a database` - closing question as too broad

Comment: You need some server side code to read and process the data. And for the `<form method="post">` you need to define the url on which you _listen_ for the data using the `action` attribute.

Comment: Can I do something with JS? is there no framework or something at least to build a json database when there is a submission? I don't know PHP
I'd welcome any resource to try and learn to do at least this...

Comment: if its just for testing, mean you want to see either value is passed in or not.. you can access the posted value using jquery/javascript and can display on the page it self.  mean enter the value click the submit and it will display the value you entered. is this what you wanna try??

Comment: @Bizarre then you should describe your use case more in detail. What do you want to do with the data? Where do you want to store it? What is the purpose of the form?

Comment: People will be able to write a message on the form along with email and name so i'd like to be able to answer them, i'd also like to have the emails to make a mailing list. 
Ideally I would receive all the data from the filled out form as an email...

Comment: Then you need you need some server service that will receive this data and processes it the way you want. How you want to do this depends on what server side technology you use.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you can use the following

https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

To get all the formdata, then you can do whatever you need to do with it.